# Java - running cmd

Tags: command-line, java

I'm trying to run a simple java test code. I'm getting a "can not find or load main class file "(something like that)

The tutorial I'm following uses this command

```
-> javac name.java (javac doesn't work, using ->java ..)
-> dir (shows the classname as a file)
 > java classname
 > outputs "hello world"
```

I can't seem to get past the ->java running.java

```
class apples //everything begins with a class - need this to do anything
{
    public static void main(String args[])//method
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }   
}
```

Comment: You should convers your `*.java` file into `*.class` file with `javac`. It is called "compiling".

Answer (score 1):

<s>There could be a few problems here. Check the following:</s>

1. Are you saving the file as the name of the class plus .java, e.g. `apples.java`
2. When you execute it, are you typing the name of the class or the name of the class file? you should be typing `java apples`, not `java apples.class` or `java apples.java`.

EDIT:

I Noticed you haven't compiled the program using `javac`, which makes the progrm unrunnable by `java [program_name]`. You need to run `javac [java_sourcde_file_name]` to generate a .class file. If `javac` doesn't work, maybe:

1. You don't have the JDK (Java Development Kit) installed and should download it from [Oracle](http://datagenetics.com/blog/december42010/spark.mpeg)
2. `javac` is not in your PATH - unlikely but possible - see http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/beginner/settingup.html.
3. `javac` runs properly but your program doesn't compile properly. this seems unlikely given the program you posted looks fine.

Comment: Nope my java file is names "running".java my class is "apples". 1] I am navigating to "running".java location dir d:\java (lists "running") and then i cant get any further than that. I've tried javac running (error:javac not recognized command). java running(error: can not find or load main class running) so then I try java apples(this is the main class) and also has can not find/load error.

Comment: your problem is that you need to install javac. look at the second part of my answer.

Comment: I installed the java SE from java.sun.com. That thought occured to me so I downloaded java jdk and installed again (twice) but with both installations it said I already had the software installed etc but I let it carry through anyway. I've already changed my Path variable and added the D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin.

Comment: go to the command line and type `dir "D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin"`. is `javac.exe` listed?

Comment: Actually looking at the site you linked it may have something to do with the path I am pointing it to. Ill go through the turial and see how that turns out.

Comment: then you need to find the path that `javac.exe` actually is in. try looking around in `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_<version>\bin`. if you find it there, add that directory (or wherever you find it) to the path.

Comment: I ran a complete computer search for javac.exe and zilch. I guess I'll try downloading/installing again.

Comment: I've changed the Path var. path to the new installation but cmd still won't recognize the javac command. 

This what I installed http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u7-downloads-1836413.html

Windows x64 90 MB    jdk-7u7-windows-x64.exe

Comment: I found it :D I didn't realise it also installed another java folder in the separate d:\program files. After I change the Path var. path it should work (hopefully).

Comment: if it worked, click the hollow check-mark on the left of the answer to mark the answer as the one that worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Apples //- need this to do anything
{
    public static void main(String args[])//everything begins with a method
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }   
}
```

Make sure you are in current directory of java file

compile as

```
javac Apples.java
```

Run as

```
java Apples
```

Before working in it , should need to know the coding convention it would be better to work java

Answer (score 0):

Well. All you have to do in Jaca is navigate you where your class files are stored and then use java "class name". You DO NOT need to put .java or .class. Just the name.

Comment: Could not find or load mian class apples. This is what I've typed in -> dir d:\java (lists my running.java file) -> java running(could not find or load...etc) -> java apples (class name) also has find/load error)

Comment: Oh. I see. You haven't compiled the files yet. You have to use javac.

Comment: Continue following Jake's answer as he is explaining possible reasons why javac is not working. I'll comment there if I find anything interesting.

Answer (score 0):

change your class name from apples to Apples (naming convention for java class names):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java

also recommend you to change the file name accordingly...

then recompile and run it

> javac Apples.java
>
> java Apples

cheers